# Combine multiple requests and subscribe sequentially with rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a loop that sends x http requests.

In some cases user can send a so many requests and that could affect server performances.

I would like to convert existing logic and be able ho manage max requests number.

Sample code

```
for( let i; i<x; i++ ) {
  this.subs= this.globalService.getData(formData, id).subscribe(data => {...}
}
```

How can I authorise triger only if the number of requests is < 10 for example otherwise wait for api response and check if current observers is less than 10 ?

It's important to subscribe sequentially and not send an array of data to not change code logic inside subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is using [`mergeMap()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) with an optional `concurrency` option.

```
range(x)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(i =>  this.globalService.getData(formData, i), 10),
  )
  .subscribe();
```

This way you can make `mergeMap()` to perform at most 10 concurrent requests.

Comment: Thanks , your answer is great, but I would know how to do this If I don't know the range number ?

Comment: I don't know what is your use-case exactly but in your example you used `for` so I guess you know the range beforehand. If not, you can use `Subject` and push `id`s (or whatever)  and `mergeMap()` will take care of the concurrency requests.

Comment: Yes I have not well described my case. I have a ui list that when click in get all will triggeran event on each event , and this event will call the http request

Comment: Then it sounds like you can use that as a source Observable instead of `range()` or an intermediate subject.